# htaccess - Category / Subcategory / Page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, parameters, subquery, categories

I have a small problem:

My URL: localhost / cat / Category / Subcategory / Page

Example: localhost / cat / movies / 3d / 7

The Code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2 [NC,L]  ## wq is Category
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2&wsq=$3 [NC,L]  ## wsq is Subcategory / but if no Subcategory and Pagination -> False it must be "&wpq="
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2&wsq=$3&wpq=$4 [NC,L]   ## wpq is Pagination
```

My current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2 [NC,L]  ## wq is Category
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2&wsq=$3 [NC,L]  ## wsq is Subcategory / but if no Subcategory and Pagination -> False it must be "&wpq="
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2&wsq=$3&wpq=$4 [NC,L]   ## wpq is Pagination

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This works as far as it should, only problem if only one category (and no subcat) is entered, then it should be checked whether parameter 2 only numbers.

If only numbers are entered, then it is not a subcategory but the Pagination parameter (then the second parameter must be "wsq" and not "wsq").

I hope you understand what I mean: D

This could be done with Php, but I think via .htaccess is better?

Thank you in advance already times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it, replace:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2&wsq=$3 [NC,L]
```

With:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2&wpq=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2&wsq=$3 [NC,L]
```

`(\d+)` (which is equivalent to `([0-9]+)` or `([[:digit:]]+)`) to match a number. This new rule being more specific, needs to be located **before** your "regular" rule (which expects letters and/or digits and/or dash).

Comment: Thank You, it Works Great ;)

But if i got to an url Like this: http://localhost/cat/?wq=filme

It dont Rewrite to http://localhost/cat/filme/


RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1.php?wq=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: Not sure to understand: if you want `/cat/?wq=filme` to be redirected on `/cat/filme`, you currently have no rule to do so.